# Read multiple variables (from stdin) in Julia with a single line of code

Tags: julia

Suppose we have to take multiple input in one line in Python 3 then:-
1st method:-

```py
x, y = input(), input()
```

2nd method:-

```py
x, y = input().split()
```

3rd method:-
Using list comprehension

```py
x, y = [int(x) for x in [x, y]]
```

4th method:-

```py
x, y = map(int, input().split())
```

So these are the methods I know in python 3.
Can anyone tell me the alternate code in Julia?

Answer (score 3):

```
readdlm(IOBuffer(readline()))
```

The best simple parser for all occasions is `readdlm`. 
It will provide you processing any user input as an array and hence will be most robust for any circumstances:

```
julia> using DelimitedFiles

julia> readdlm(IOBuffer(readline()))
z b c
1×3 Array{Any,2}:
 "z"  "b"  "c"

julia> readdlm(IOBuffer(readline()))
1 2
1×2 Array{Float64,2}:
 1.0  2.0
```

Since it is an Array the same multi-argument assignment will work as in Python

```
julia> x, y = readdlm(IOBuffer(readline()))
1 2 3
1×3 Array{Float64,2}:
 1.0  2.0  3.0

julia> x, y 
(1.0, 2.0)
```

Answer (score 1):

As we can't directly use input function I implemented like this in Julia.

```
function input()  
        x, y= readline(stdin), readline(stdin)  
end
```

So I hope you liked this one.